# Geotagging of Salesforce record from Salesforce Mobile Application

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, geolocation, salesforce-mobile-app

We have a Lightning Web Component, which will be viewed from the Salesforce mobile application. When the user will save a record from the Lightning Web Component, we would like to Geotag the record with the user's current location.

Based on the URL, it looks like it's feasible to get the user's location from Lightning Web Component:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_locationservice_considerations

So, we tried the sample LWC component from the below URL:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_locationservice_example

We can see the component in Salesforce mobile app, but it can't provide the location on click of "Get Current Location" button.[image]

Can someone please confirm, if it is feasible from the Salesforce Mobile app to read geolocation data, if yes have you come across any limitations with lwc.use_locationservice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
   fetchUserCurrentLocation() {  
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {

                // Get the Latitude and Longitude from Geolocation API
                this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;                
                
            });
        }
    }
```

By using navigator.geolocation, we are able to get the current location of user in Desktop browser as well as Salesforce mobile app.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_geolocation.asp